# Custom line break on specified character

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to be able to word break an email, after the @ sign.

So it would look like the following

```
 id | name    | email       | status
--------------------------------------
 1  | Bob joe | bjoe        | active
    |         | @gmail.com  | 
--------------------------------------
 2  | jay c   | jc@gmail.com| active
--------------------------------------
 3  | David   | dsmith      | inactive
    | Smith   | @yahoo.com  | 
                  ^ I want it to break the email right before the @sign
```

What I have so far is this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/9rjW3/**

Here is the same code below:

CSS

```
table{ 
    table-layout:fixed;  

    -ms-word-break: break-all; 
    word-break: break-all; 
    word-break: break-word; 

    width: 330px;
}

table td{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="fixed" border="1">
    <col width="20px" />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col width="70px" />
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Kaimana Marek</td>
        <td>thisisatest@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Joshua Bourguignon</td>
        <td>tasdflknadsfl@gmail.com</td>
        <td>Inactive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Ekkehard Mehmud</td>
        <td>asdflknasdc@yahoo.com</td>
        <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to line break a string with a custom character like the `@` sign?

Comment: Not with only HTML and CSS, you must use jQuery language....

Comment: Not doable with HTML only, unless you force it with a break line `<br/>`

Comment: @AmirBawab I prefer not to add a <br/>, I only want it to break if the email is too long, not every time.

Comment: @LucaDetomi How would I go about doing this with jQuery?

Comment: What about cases like `absurdly.long.email.address.who.does.this@abc.com`? Still want to break on the @?

Comment: @Chris yes, as long as the `@abc.com`, I am okay with that because those are more rare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some more help, and I found out this was the best way to do it

**http://jsfiddle.net/9rjW3/10/**

```
$('tr + tr td:nth-child(3) span').html(function(i,h){
    return $(this).height() > 18 ? h.replace(/@/g, '\n@') : h;
});
```

Credit goes to: [David Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22973540/1509580)

Answer (score 1):

Something like `s.replace(/([^\n]{10})/g, '$1\n');` where `{10}` is the number of characters after which you want to add a break.

Also, to make it look consistent it would be best to use monospace characters, because otherwise the width of your characters varies significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        text = text.replace("@", "<br/>@");
        $(this).html(text);
    });
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/monsur_hoq/9rjW3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `<wbr>` tag before each “@” character. This is a nonstandard but widely supported tag for optional line break. The issue of [allowing line breaks](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) is complicated, and the good old `<wbr>` isn’t as clear-cut as it used to be, due to changes in browsers. To maximize the odds, you could use the more complicated approach of adding

```
<wbr><a class=wbr></a>
```

before each “@”, with the CSS code

```
.wbr:after { content: "\00200B"; }
```

which adds U+200B, the character-level optional line break, honored by some browsers that stopped supporting `<wbr>`.

Depending on the requirements, you can do the insertion programmatically with JavaScript (or specifically with jQuery), or (manually or programmatically) when generating the HTML document.