# Jquery won't let me add $(this).html();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hoping someone smarter than me can figure this out, I feel like I am really close...

Check it out here: **http://jsfiddle.net/9rjW3/4/**

This is the Jquery I added

```
$('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {

    $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(function () {

        if($('span').height() > 18)
            return $(this).html().replace('@','\n@');
        else
            return 'this';

    })

})
```

It works, but the only problem is I haven't figure out how to change "this" to the value of the cell...

When I try to change

```
return 'this';
```

to

```
return $(this).html();
```

It doesn't work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally suggest:

```
$('tr + tr td:nth-child(3) span').html(function(i,h){
    return $(this).height() > 18 ? h.replace(/@/g, '\n@') : h;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9rjW3/9/).

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `$(this).html`, you already have that directly available.

```
$('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {    
    $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(function (index, html) {    
        if($('span').height() > 18) {
            return html.replace('@', '<br />@');
        } else {
            return html;
        }
    });
});
```

It is correctly adding `\n` before `@`, you can see it in the debugging console. you likely instead meant to add a `<br />`

Update:

Your logic for wrapping after a certain height isn't going to work because the text will never wrap in a table cell unless you specifically set the width of the table cell. You'll have to either always append the break, or give that column a set width.

Comment: I tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9rjW3/5/ and it doesn't seem to be adding the `\n@`

Comment: It is for me, ? i see `thisisatestdummy@gmail.com`

Comment: @Arian What does this show you in the console: http://jsfiddle.net/YTyq2/. I see 19.

Comment: hahaha. zoom your browser out to 100%. try it. now zoom to 90%. try it. the height probably isn't the best thing to measure this with.

Comment: @KevinB I feel like I am going crazy lol, this is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/HCmlwRr.png

Comment: Why are you testing the height of the span?

Comment: I am trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22971297/custom-line-break-on-specified-character

Comment: right, but why height? text doesn't wrap in table cells.

Comment: I don't think there is a good option in this case other than setting the width of that column specifically by wrapping the content of the cell in a div with a set width.